# Leave Reviews via Google Places API

Tags: api, google-places-api, google-places

Does the Google Places API allow writing of reviews via third party websites/apps? I'm tired of asking customers to leave reviews on Google, Yelp, Thumbtack, and Facebook for local businesses.

I've scoured all the documentation, but can't find an answer.
https://developers.google.com/places/

If it's not possible, has anyone ever had success asking Google to change a policy?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. You can add places, but these are only available in your own application (unless they get added enough to be added 'globally').

When it's just about reviews, there are other apis present.

Asking google to change a policy? I've tried to have my country added to google and despite they actually have a data center present, it look them over 4 years to add it to their view of the world...

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3506) on Google places issue tracker is the actual issue on their bug tracker. As of april 2016 it says PendingFurtherReview. Star it for updates.